# Question about distribution through GitHub Action and Docker Compose

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to build a CI/CD environment using GitHub Action and Docker Compose for project using java/spring, but I get error such as " err: can't find a sufficient configuration file in this directory or any parent: not found during docker compose up -d process."
Docker-compose-yml exists.

**Below is the github-action script**

```
name: Java CI with Gradle

on:
  push:
    branches: ["dev"]
  pull_request:
    branches: ["dev"]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '11'
          distribution: 'temurin'

      - name: make application.properties
        run: |
          mkdir ./src/main/resources
          cd ./src/main/resources 
          touch ./application.properties 
          echo "${{ secrets.APPLICATION }}" > ./application.properties 

        shell: bash

      - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
        run: chmod +x gradlew

      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: ./gradlew clean build -x test

      - name: docker login
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_TOKEN }}

      - name: Docker build & push
        run: |
          docker build -f Dockerfile -t ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/${{ secrets.PROJECT_NAME }} .
          docker push ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/${{ secrets.PROJECT_NAME }}

      ## deploy to production
      - name: Deploy to dev
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.AWS_HOST }} # EC2 퍼블릭 IPv4 DNS
          username: ${{ secrets.AWS_USERNAME }} # ubuntu
          key: ${{ secrets.AWS_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          envs: GITHUB_SHA
          source: "docker-compose.yaml"
          script: |
            sudo docker rm - f $(docker ps -qa)
            sudo docker pull redis
            sudo docker pull ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/${{ secrets.PROJECT_NAME }}
            docker-compose up -d            
            docker image prune -f

      - name: why
        run: |
          ls
          pwd
```

**below is docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - manager-network

  lockmanager:
    image: asdss/manager
    container_name: ime_manager
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - manager-network
    depends_on:
      - redis

networks:
  manager-network:
    external: true
```

**below is Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:11
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

This is my first question. It's a very inexperienced question, but please take good care of it. THANK YOU ALL

Comment: You're using some third-party GitHub Action named `appleboy/ssh-action` to deploy to your server. You added `source: "docker-compose.yaml"` to that which I guess you assumed would trigger it to copy the `docker-compose.yaml` file to your server? But looking at the documentation for that GitHub Action I don't see any mention of using a `source` setting to get it to do something like that: https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action in fact there is no mention of a `source` input variable in that documentation at all.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!! unfortunately,, I change my script, but it doesn't work... I really don't know why it doesn't

Comment: You changed it to what? We can't help you with that if we can't see what you are trying. So far you haven't showed that you have done anything to actually copy the docker compose file to the server, so that is why it is not working.